# Create nGramms out of text with blacklist

Tags: java, n-gram

My Problem is, that I need to create 1,2,3-Gramms with the possibility to remove single words from these ngramms afterwards.

Example:

"The dog likes the car"

-> "The dog likes", "dog likes the", "likes the car".

Now I want to remove single tokens like "the". For that reason I can't use Arrays because we can't remove entries. After I removed a token, the nGramm should be handled as 1-gram or 2-Gram depending how many tokens are removed. It is important for me that the blackwords / stopwords are removed after the ngram-creation.

Thank you for your help, finding a data structure.

Loro

Comment: What have you investigated so far for possible candidates for data structures (other than arrays)?

Comment: Have you considered using a LinkedList instead of an array? It comes with a numeber of remove methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried ArrayList but I got performance problems. Furthermore I tried HashMaps, which I stored in ArrayLists. But in this case I was not able to store three values in one hashmap value.

Comment: In general I have problems to store n values somehow that I can edit them but have them also stored as ONE ngram :/

Comment: I encourage you to try a LinkedList. The cost of the remove operation on a LinkedList is very small.